# Checkmarx security vulnerability tool has detected Client_DOM_Stored_Code_Injection vulnerability in jquery 3.5.1 min.js How do we resolve this risk

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Checkmarx security vulnerability tool has detected Client_DOM_Stored_Code_Injection vulnerability in jquery 3.5.1 min.js How do we resolve this risk.

The method o), embeds untrusted data in generated output with a, at line 1504 of src\main\webapp\jquery.min.js. This untrusted data is embedded into the output without proper sanitization or encoding, enabling an attacker to inject malicious code into the generated web-page.

The attacker can inject the malicious payload into the victim client, via client-side storage mechanism result. This is read by the client in the while method, at line 1529 of src\main\webapp\jquery.min.js. The client evaluates this code, and executes it.

How to resolve this.iam using Jquery 3.5.1.min.js.

[image: Checkmark Error]

How to resolve this,please help

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You might first consider using a newer more modern version of jQuery. 3.5.1 was released May 4, 2020. Current version is 3.7.1 was released in August: https://blog.jquery.com/2023/08/28/jquery-3-7-1-released-reliable-table-row-dimensions/